# Load data in a chart. Problem, loading the same value from the table to the chart

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, charts

I am programming vb.net using ms-Access. I am trying to create a chart, actually I already have it and populate it from a table from MS-access. The problem is that is getting only the first value and repeating it.

```
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count
                Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(rs.Fields("Name").Value, rs.Fields("ID").Value)
            Next
```

For example: My first value from the table is called Jhon, and I have 5 people on my table.The chart is loaded with 5 Jhons! 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through records:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(rs.Fields("Name").Value, rs.Fields("ID").Value)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was using totally wrong commands, did not know about this one! Thanks